# How to input characters with HEX codes ending with "0"?

Tags: macos, keyboard, monterey, unicode

I've recently upgraded to Monterey, and while I normally use the Unicode HEX keyboard to input accented/special characters, it ignores characters whose codes start and end with "0", making it impossible to input "a with grave accent" (U+00E0), but "ᄐ" (U+1110) and "é" (U+00E9) work.

Seems like a bug, and is a big nuisance.

Update: Fixed as of MacOS 13.3!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think all you can do about this is [complain to Apple](http://www.apple.com/feedback) and use [Character Viewer](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-emoji-and-symbols-on-mac-mchlp1560/12.0/mac/12.0) or the [ABC Extended](https://sites.psu.edu/symbolcodes/mac/codemacext/) keyboard instead.

Making a custom layout for the characters you need most often with [Ukelele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/) may also make sense.  Or creating [text replacements](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/replace-text-punctuation-documents-mac-mh35735/mac) for them (for example using the hex codes as the triggers).

Update:  Still broken as of MacOS 12.6

Update:  Still broken as of MacOS 13.2

Update: FIXED AS OF MACOS 13.3

I think 256 codepoints are affected, but not all are occupied.  This chart shows them:

[image]