# With "Unicode Hex Input", the code for lower-case "pi" (03C0) doesn't work

Tags: macos, keyboard, unicode

I'm trying to type "pi" (unicode 03C0) via the Unicode + Hex Input setup. That generally works fine; like when I hold down the option key and type 2014, I get the emdash character (like this: —). However, the code for pi does nothing.

Now, I guess it could be that the fonts involved (I've tried here, in a Terminal window, and some other web inputs) simply don't have a pi character, but it seems a little weird that none I've tried do. I mean, pi is hardly an obscure symbol.

Is there a good way of figuring out what's going on?

Comment: Answered here   https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/437833/how-to-input-characters-with-hex-codes-ending-with-0

Comment: As Tom already pointed out, this is a duplicate of: [How to input characters with HEX codes ending with "0"?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/437833/how-to-input-characters-with-hex-codes-ending-with-0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug was fixed in 13.3, you just need to update macOS

Comment: Weird bug, but at least it's fixed!  Thanks.

Comment: ... and indeed it works now